# Jenkins dynamically set $DEFAULT_CONTENT

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy

I need to execute a script (groovy) and use the content generated by the script for sending an email. The body of the email is the content. I am not sure how to do this as $DEFAULT_CONTENT is mentioned to be a token (enabled by token plugin). Can some one help me on how to achieve this. I am using the execute groovy script and Email-ext plugin. Thanks and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of Email-ext+plugin
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

$DEFAULT_CONTENT should be a variable filled from the Default Content field from the global configuration page

I haven't used Email-Ext in plain groovy, but in pipeline I use it like the following:

```
     emailext attachLog: true, compressLog: true, recipientProviders: [culprits()],
              subject: "Issue on branch ${env.BRANCH_NAME}",
              body: """<p>Job ${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} failed</p>
                       <p>Result of my Script ${MY_SCRIPT_RESULT}</p>
                       <p>Check console output at <a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</a></p>"""
```

Here ${MY_SCRIPT_RESULT} would be the value of variable MY_SCRIPT_RESULT.
MY_SCRIPT_RESULT could be a variable I exported to variable environment for instance